# Azure Data Factory: Get the filename and record number of the offending record

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to ingest a bunch of files and the only error I get in Azure Data Factory is this -

Operation on target Copy isolation_advice_details to SQL failed: ErrorCode=PolybaseOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error happened when loading data into SQL Data Warehouse. Operation: 'Polybase operation'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=HdfsBridge::recordReaderFillBuffer - Unexpected error encountered filling record reader buffer: HadoopExecutionException: Too long string in column [-1]: Actual len = [251]. MaxLEN=[250],Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=107090,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=107090,State=1,

Message=HdfsBridge::recordReaderFillBuffer - Unexpected error encountered filling record reader buffer: HadoopExecutionException: Too long string in column [-1]: Actual len = [251]. MaxLEN=[250],},],'

It is frustrating because there are thousands of files in there. How do I find out which record in which file is this happening?

Comment: Did you find a way around this ?

Comment: Hi Kartik, no I did not. But we moved on in terms of problem fixing with some other way. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for the information, if you feel it is relevant or general solution that others can adopt in similar situation. Please do share it as an answer below. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This could mostly be with a column with `Date` or `timestamp` value. You can ALTER the table with right datatype once you identify one.

Follow this official MS doc
[ADF throws error: Unexpected error encountered filling record reader buffer ClassCastException](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics-blog/adf-throws-error-unexpected-error-encountered-filling-record/ba-p/1403116) for detailed troubleshooting.

Comment: This is in a live production environment and we need to find the offending record. We are not allowed to change the pipeline to get to the bad records etc. I know this is silly, but yeah that's the position we are in. Just wondered why does Azure mention the error and not where it found the error! There should be somewhere it is recording this!

Comment: I agree, did you find anything anything more.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use "Fault Tolerance" in the "Copy to SQL" settings. This will definitely mitigate the problem. However, it wasn't appropriate for us, as setting fault tolerance on dozens of pipelines would mean a greater level of manual interaction in daily maintenance which our current resourcing was not geared to cope with. It might work for someone else :)